# Ant compile and maven packaging

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Our build system uses ANT for code compilation and MAVEN for generating the compile/runtime classpath and static preprocessing. We are moving towards adopting MAVEN for our end to end build lifecycle which i don't think will happen anytime sooner. Hence, in the interim, we decided to create a packaged artifact using MAVEN. I ended up using maven-assembly-plugin for that purpose, just because i could feed in whats needed to create the package from the ant compiled artifacts, which I achieve by defining a assembly descriptor within the pom. However, we also wanted to include the dependency jars of the project into the same final artifact, which is where I need some help.

I created a separate profile within the pom.xml and added assembly.xml as the descriptor.

```
    <profile>
        <id>assemblyjar</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>${project.basedir}/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                        <tarLongFileMode>gnu</tarLongFileMode>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Here is how the assembly file look like:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
<id>dist</id>
<includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
<formats>
 <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<dependencySets>
 <dependencySet>
    <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
    <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
    <unpack>false</unpack>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
    <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
    <includes></includes>
</dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
<fileSets>
<fileSet>
  <includes>
    <include>abcd/**</include>
    <include>efgh/**</include>
  </includes>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    <exclude>**/*.log*</exclude>
  </excludes>
  <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
</fileSet>
```

When i execute assembly:single -Passemblyjar, it creates a fat jar with the contents mentioned in the assembly, however it doesnt create directories of the dependency jars as per the groupId & artifactId.

When I unjar the artifact, the dependency jar is created right away under the project basedir

```
25962 Mon Apr 28 15:46:08 PDT 2014 project-2.0.0/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar  
159509 Mon Apr 28 15:46:08 PDT 2014 project-2.0.0/commons-io-2.0.1.jar 
43581 Mon Apr 28 15:46:10 PDT 2014 project-2.0.0/asm-3.3.1.jar  
597777 Mon Apr 28 15:46:08 PDT 2014 project-2.0.0/testng-6.3.1.jar
```

Is there a way to let maven create the directory structure as per the groupId and artifactId of the dependency jars as shown below. The following 4 jars are just examples, wherein real there are about 500 jars in different locations.

```
25962 Mon Apr 28 15:46:08 PDT 2014 project-2.0.0/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.4/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
159509 Mon Apr 28 15:46:08 PDT 2014 project-2.0.0/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/commons-io-2.0.1.jar
43581 Mon Apr 28 15:46:10 PDT 2014 project-2.0.0/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar
597777 Mon Apr 28 15:46:08 PDT 2014 project-2.0.0/org/testng/testng/6.3.1/testng-6.3.1.jar
```

Appreciate your inputs on this..

Comment: Would it help if you set outputFileNameMapping on the dependency set. I think it defaults to ${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}.${artifact.extension}.

Comment: Thanks Niels, doesnt make any difference :(

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy dependencies prior to your assembling, you can specify the copy goal to use repository layout, which I think is what you are after.

Then just assemble it as a fileset afterwards from `${project.build.directory}/dependency`, which is the default output directory for the copy goal

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <useRepositoryLayout>true</useRepositoryLayout>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
          <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks Niels, let me try this

Comment: Thanks Niels, appreciate your help on this.. Though it doesn't extract the jars in the groupId artifactId format, I used it to copy the dependencies to the lib folder and it works like a charm..

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your assembly plugin tag

```
<descriptorRefs>
    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
</descriptorRefs>
```

The final configuration should look something like

```
<plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.4</version>
     <configuration>
     <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
     <descriptors>
            <descriptor>${project.basedir}/assembly.xml</descriptor>
     </descriptors>
     <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
     </descriptorRefs>
     <tarLongFileMode>gnu</tarLongFileMode>
     <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
           <execution>
                 <id>make-assembly</id>
                 <phase>package</phase>
                 <goals>
                       <goal>single</goal>
                 </goals>
           </execution>
     </executions>
```